# Implicitly-declared Move-Operations do not fallback to Copy?

Tags: c++, copy, move, c++11, implicit

Do I read  N3291 "12.8.(11/15/28) Copying and moving class objects class.copy]" correct that the implicitly-declared **move constructor**

- does an element-wise **move** of all non-static data-members (probably via respectively defined `T(T&&)`
- and if any non-static data-member can not be moved, the implicit move-constructor will be marked as deleted **and not tried to be copied** as a "fallback"? (yes, move is defined for built-in types, but actually is a copy).

and likewise the **move-assign**, using the respective `T operator=(T&&)` of the elements.

Example:

```
struct CopyOnly {
    CopyOnly();
    CopyOnly(const CopyOnly&);
}; // declaring a copy means no implicit move.

struct Question {
    std::vector<int> data_;
    CopyOnly         copyOnly_;
};
```

The class `Question`

- will have implicitly-declared *copy-constructor* and *assign*
- will have implicitly-declared *move-constructor* and *move-assign*, **but they will be `=delete`d**, because the non-static data-member `data_` is **only *copyable*, but not *movable***?

**Update.** A side-question: For `Question q;` will `std::move(q)` still work? Will the fallback to copy happen there? Or will the *implicitly-declared* move-ctor force the compiler to stop with an error? [Here](https://ideone.com/27zSt) it does compile.

**Update 2.** What does the compiler generate for the non-movable data-members if I declare the move-ctor `Question(Question&&) =default`? Does it *then* fallback to copying those?

Comment: Do you mean that `copyOnly_` is the reason for `Question` being not movable instead of `data_` or do I miss something important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read it incorrectly. This would break lots of C++03 classes in cases such as the following

```
Question getQuestion();
Question q(getQuestion()); // use of deleted move constructor!
```

Instead, the FDIS says that a move constructor will be declared iff {there is no user declared {copy constructor, {copy, move} assignment operator, destructor} and *the implicitly declared move constructor would not be defined as deleted*}.

Regarding **Update 2**. It has been brought to my attention that if you explicitly-default the move constructor, it will be defined as deleted by the condition

> for the move constructor, a non-static data member or direct or virtual base class with a type that does not have a move constructor and is not trivially copyable.

In the following, the move constructor will be defined as **deleted**, because `CopyOnly` is not trivially copyable.

```
 struct Question 
 {
        std::vector<int> data_;
        CopyOnly         copyOnly_;

        Question(Question&&) = default;
 };
```

Comment: Got it! I overlooked the last bullet-item. *Grummel*. Good thing I asked.

Comment: Can you also point me to the right paragraph for my "Update 2" part?

Comment: Excellent. That is quite a set of things one has to entangle.

Comment: @towi, I was wrong with my comment-answer on "Update 2". I will add corresponding parts to my answer.

Comment: bah, SO doesn't let me edit my answer because I already edited my own posts 15 times today. need to wait until tomorrow :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Don't you worry. Updated it on your behalf :)

Comment: Copy-only sub-objects, whether member or base, are not a problem for defaulted move-constructor: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aedd5ee6666a2e58